# Peewee 1:n mapping duplicates in join

Tags: peewee, flask-peewee

I have some peewee models with 1:n mapping and backrefs, like so:

```
class Userr(BaseModel):
    rowId = BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    userId = CharField()

class UserName(BaseModel):
    rowId = BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = TextField()
    user = ForeignKeyField(Userr, backref='userNames')

class UserAddress(BaseModel):
    rowId = BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    address = TextField()
    user = ForeignKeyField(Userr, backref='userAddresses')
```

I want to write a query where I can get all `Userrs` with their `UserName`s and `UserAddress`es

`users = Userr.select().join(UserName).switch(Userr).join(UserAddress)`

But I get duplicate rows with this. When I have one `Userr` with 2 `UserName`s, I get 2 rows, where each `Userr.userNames` (the backref) contains both the `UserName`s. How can I avoid these duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.distinct()`, e.g.

```
users = Userr.select().join(...).distinct()
```

If you want to pre-fetch all their related addresses and user-names, then you can try using `prefetch()`:

```
users = prefetch(Userr, UserName, UserAddress)
```

See the docs: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/relationships.html#list-users-and-all-their-tweets

Comment: Yeah that works, but what is wrong with the query?

Comment: Read up on how relational databases work.